# Deploy a python flask app with heroku database to heroku

Tags: python, database, postgresql, flask, heroku

I was able to launch my flask app when it wasn't using the database yet. How do I set-up the database in heroku. I always run `export DATABASE_URL=<URI>` in the terminal whenever I run my flask app. I tried to follow tutorials online but nothing works so far.

This is my directory

[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLejX.png)

This is my Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn wsgi:app
heroku ps:scale web
```

This is my requirements.txt:

```
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
gunicorn==19.10.0
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

This is my wsgi.py when I placed my flask app inside the flask_qa folder:

```
from flask_qa import create_app

app = create_app()
```

This is the heroku log:

[heroku log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHTeQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set the app config using

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgres://(you get the restof uri in heroku)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] =False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```